# Count twice if certain condition satisfies in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a scenario where I need to display total number of attendees of an event. With the help of registration form I have already captured the details of people who are attending and my table looks like below.

---

```
ID     | NAME     | PHONE_NUMBER     | IS_LIFE_PARTNER_ATTENDING
```

---

```
1      | ABC      | 1234567890       | N
```

---

```
2      | PQR      | 1234567891       | Y
```

---

```
3      | XYZ      | 1234567892       | N
```

I can easily display number of registrations by using count(id). But while displaying number of attendees I have to consider as two attendees if registrant is coming with his/her partner. (identified by IS_LIFE_PARTNER_ATTEDNING column)

So, in the above case, the number of registrants are 3, but number of attendees are 4, because "PQR" is coming with his/her life partner.

How can we do this in mysql query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT 
SUM( 1 + (IS_LIFE_PARTNER_ATTEDNING = 'Y')) AS totalAttendees
FROM your_table;
```

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/859009/1/0)</kbd>

Since boolean expression resolves into `0/1` in `MySQL` so that you can capitalize this in your case.

**Note:**

`SUM(a=b) returns 1 only if a is equal to b otherwise it returns 0`

**Caution:**

*Never underestimate these parentheses `(IS_LIFE_PARTNER_ATTEDNING = 'Y')`. If you omit them then the whole summation would result in `zero(0)`.

<sub>* [because of operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Use `SUM` with `CASE`

```
SELECT 
Name,
SUM(CASE WHEN IS_LIFE_PARTNER_ATTEDNING='y' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END ) AS'Attendes'
FROM
table
GROUP by name
```